# SQL Server Linked Server error

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, linked-server, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am using SQL Server 2008 on Windows Server 2003. I want to use a linked server to open a Visual Foxpro DBF file, using driver Microsoft OLD DB Provider for Visual Foxpro from SQL Server 2008 linked server feature.

When I establish linked server connection by using Microsoft OLD DB Provider for Visual Foxpro, to open a Foxpro DBF file, I meet with the following error, any ideas what is wrong?

```
Can not retrieve required data from this request (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Src)

Meeting exception when executing Transact-SQL or batch (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

Error from Microsoft OLD DB Provider interface "VFPOLEDB" of linked server "DBFServer", access is defined.

Can not retrieved required interface "IID_IDBSchemaRowset" from OLE DB interface "VFPOLEDB" of linked server "DBFServer"
```

(Microsoft SQL Server error 7399)

regards,
George

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check 'Allow Inprocess' on the VFPOLEDB provider:

See Cindy Winegarden's answer on http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/e54d20dd-b65b-4cff-9349-6499e6e069e2 for how to do it.

Edit: this is the relevant part of the answer:

> Here's what Stepahnie posted to her thread in the
>   microsoft.public.data.oledb NNTP newsgroup on April 10:
>
> "Finally, I found an option ' Allow inprocess' in linked server ->
>   providers -> VFPOLEDB in MSSQL2005.  With enable this option, I can
>   connect to vfp with oledb.  While diabling this option, it works only
>   50% with successful connection....
>
> And I have another MSSQL2005 with the same setup (except the option
>   'allow inprocess' disabled), all the connection make to vfp is 100%
>   successful... "
>
> I looked and found that, as she said, in Server Objects > Linked
>   Servers > Providers > VFPOLEDB > General tab > Provider options >
>   Allow inprocess. Also, you can change the InProcess setting with the
>   following code:

```
USE [master]
GO
EXEC master.dbo.sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'VFPOLEDB', N'AllowInProcess', 1
GO
```